# How to work with RecyclerView in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button, android-recyclerview

I have used following code in `main_activity.xml` to add `Floating Button`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
  android:id="@+id/fab"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
  android:layout_margin="16dp"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh" />
```

I am using following method to load data in `RecyclerView`:

```
 public void getWarehouse(){
  .....
    //Some retrofit calls 
  .....
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.staggering_grid);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    mAdapter = new StaggeredGridAdapter(mContext);
    mAdapter.addItems(response);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    GridItemSpaces decoration = new GridItemSpaces(10);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
}
```

Purpose of `getWareHouse()` method:
Loading data in `RecyclerView Staggered Grid View`.

Purpose of `FloatingButton`:
To refresh the data from `API calls`. In short I am calling `getWareHouse()` from `OnClickListner` of `FloatingActionButton`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    wareHousAPIWrapper = new WareHousAPIWrapper(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.this);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    FloatingActionButton mFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            wareHousAPIWrapper.getWarehouse();
        }
    });

    if (mToolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("sample");
    }
    wareHousAPIWrapper.getWarehouse();

}
```

I can see the loaded data in `RecyclerView` when clicking on `FloatingButton` but Everytime I am clicking the refresh length of `Staggered` is getting increases.

Why is it happening?

See the screenshot:

First click of refresh button:
[image]

After 10-20 times:
[image]

## Edit-1 `getWarehouse` method definition

```
 //Making request to API
    adapter.create(WarehouseAPI.class).getWarehouse()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Warehouse>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "OnCompleted ()");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Error:" + e.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Warehouse> response) {
                    // code for `RecyclerView` I have posted above
                }

            });
```

Comment: why are you creating new reference object of `RecyclerView` every time in  `getWarehouse()`? you just need only `add` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Now I am not creating a new `RecyclerView` and passing in same but still facing some situation

Comment: can you post more code?

Comment: @kishorejethava So, I have added `MainActivity.onCreate` method where I am calling `wareHousAPIWrapper.getWarehouse();` to load data into recyclerview and you can also see the code of `Fab` button onclick listner and rest of the processing is written in `getWarehouse` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With every call to `wareHouseAPIWrapper.getWarehouse()`, you are adding another item decorator to `mRecyclerView`. This is causing the items in the `RecyclerView` to become smaller every time you click the refresh button. You should only add an item decorator when initializing the activity, like so:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    wareHousAPIWrapper = new WareHousAPIWrapper(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.this);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    FloatingActionButton mFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            wareHousAPIWrapper.getWarehouse();
        }
    });

    if (mToolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("sample");
    }

    wareHousAPIWrapper.getWarehouse();
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.staggering_grid);
    GridItemSpaces decoration = new GridItemSpaces(10);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
}
```

Item decorators no longer need to be added in `getWarehouse()`:

```
public void getWarehouse(){
  .....
    //Some retrofit calls 
  .....
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.staggering_grid);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    mAdapter = new StaggeredGridAdapter(mContext);
    mAdapter.addItems(response);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the "response" in `mAdapter.addItems(response);` getting after the retrofit calls. It's not possible to access the response in `onCreate` method. I am pasting the code How I am getting the response using `Retrofit` and `Rx-java`

Comment: Also as per above code you are calling `getResponse` only on `FloatingButton` onCLickListner. I also want to make request when the activity is loaded (As you can checkout the in onCreate method in question post)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I moved some code around to fix the issues. :)